# Merge items of an array into a single object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array or arrays of objects, with two properties each, one of which is an array. So it looks something like this:

```
[
 [{
   name: 'Object1',
   items: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
 }],
 [{
   name: 'Object2',
   items: ['item4', 'item5', 'item6']
 }],
 [{
   name: 'Object3',
   items: ['item7', 'item8', 'item9']
 }]

]
```

What I want to do is make so that all items will be stored into `Object 1`. So basically, this is what I want it to look like:

```
[
 {
   name: 'Object1',
   items: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7', 'item8', 'item9']
 }
]
```

I suppose I could just create a new object and map each item then concatenate them, but I am looking for a more efficient way to do this. What would be the best way to get this done?

Comment: So you're discarding duplicate keys? What's the criteria for which value remains in the output?

Comment: Map and concatenate IMO.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts there are no duplicate keys in this case.

Comment: @theJuls the duplicate key is `name`.

Comment: why are the inner objects wrapped in arrays?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get all items in a single array. Then assign the array to the `items` property.

Note: `Array.flatMap()` is not supported by IE and Edge.

```js
const arr = [[{"name":"Object1","items":["item1","item2","item3"]}],[{"name":"Object2","items":["item4","item5","item6"]}],[{"name":"Object3","items":["item7","item8","item9"]}]];

const result = [{
  name: 'Object1',
  items: arr.flatMap(([o]) => o.items)
}];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Note: `flatMap()` is tagged as experimental [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Answer (score 1):

With es5 you can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
  combined with [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) as following:

```
const newArray = oldArray.reduce((list, current) => list.concat(current[0].items), [])
```

Live example code:

```js
const arr = [
 [{
   name: 'Object1',
   items: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
 }],
 [{
   name: 'Object2',
   items: ['item4', 'item5', 'item6']
 }],
 [{
   name: 'Object3',
   items: ['item7', 'item8', 'item9']
 }]

]

const y = arr.reduce((list, current) => list.concat(current[0].items), [])

console.log(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the spread operator to do it.

```
var sourceArray = [
 [{
   name: 'Object1',
   items: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
 }],
 [{
   name: 'Object2',
   items: ['item4', 'item5', 'item6']
 }],
 [{
   name: 'Object3',
   items: ['item7', 'item8', 'item9']
 }]
];

var targetArray = [];

sourceArray.forEach(item => {
    targetArray = [...targetArray, ...item[0].items];
})
```

...item[0].items should be changed to item.items if the inner objects shouldn't be wrapped in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use map() function like this code

```
var x=[
 [{
   name: 'Object1',
   items: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
 }],
 [{
   name: 'Object2',
   items: ['item4', 'item5', 'item6']
 }],
 [{
   name: 'Object3',
   items: ['item7', 'item8', 'item9']
 }]
];
var name='';
var a=[];
x.map((element,i)=>{ //here pass element and index to first map
 element.map(el=>{
if(i==0){ // check if index is 0 so name here is required for new object 
 name=el.name;
 }
 el.items.map(item=>{
 a.push(item); // here add each items to the items array
 });
});
});
var obj={ // create new object with name and items array
name:name,
items:a
};
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Isolating the core merge logic

Start by writing the logic to merge just 2 objects. This is where you explicitly say:

> "We use the first `name` we see, and concatenate the `items`"

```js
const mergeObjects = (obj1, obj2) => ({
  name: obj1.name || obj2.name,
  items: obj1.items.concat(obj2.items)
});

console.log(
  mergeObjects(
    { name: 'Object1', items: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'] },
    { name: 'Object2', items: ['item4', 'item5', 'item6'] }
  )
);
```

Two challenges remain:

- Working with the nested objects: `[ { /* .... */ } ]`
- Working with a list of objects

### Getting the objects out of their arrays

The first one can be tackled by using a helper that takes the objects out of their arrays, merges them, and wraps them back in an array:

```
const mergeNestedObjects = ([obj1], [obj2]) => [mergeObjects(obj1, obj2)];
```

### Using reduce to apply the logic to a list

The second one is a matter of using reduce!

```js
const mergeObjects = (obj1, obj2) => ({
  name: obj1.name || obj2.name,
  items: obj1.items.concat(obj2.items)
});

const mergeNestedObjects = ([obj1], [obj2]) => [mergeObjects(obj1, obj2)];

const data=[[{name:"Object1",items:["item1","item2","item3"]}],[{name:"Object2",items:["item4","item5","item6"]}],[{name:"Object3",items:["item7","item8","item9"]}]];


console.log(
  data.reduce(mergeNestedObjects)
)
```

### A note on using a seed value for reduce

There's still one catch: this operation can only be used on arrays of lengths `>= 2`; we need at least two items to perform our merge.

To tackle this issue, we can create a "seed" value. An empty item:

```
data.reduce(mergeNestedObjects, [ { name: null, items: [] } ]);
```